Regex to extract a part of URL using stringr r package
I have the following URLS:
www.google.com?utm_source=site_corriere&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box
www.google.com?utm_source=site_rep&utm_medium=display&utm_content=box
www.google.com?utm_source=site_fattoquotidiano&utm_medium=social&utm_content=box
www.google.com?utm_source=site_inter&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box
www.google.com?utm_source=site_foglio&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box
Using the package stringr, I want the extract only the values between "utm_source=" and "&"
So I expect to have:
site_corriere
site_rep
site_fattoquotidiano
site_inter
site_foglio
I am using this regex

(?<=utm_source=)(.*)(?=&)

but it is not working correctly because it is not excluding this part &utm_medium=video&utm_content=box
Could you please help me?
Thanks

If you slightly change your regex pattern to the following it should work:
(?<=\butm_source=)[^&]+

R script:
library(stringr)

x <- c("www.google.com?utm_source=site_corriere&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box",
       "www.google.com?utm_source=site_rep&utm_medium=display&utm_content=box",
       "www.google.com?utm_source=site_fattoquotidiano&utm_medium=social&utm_content=box",
       "www.google.com?utm_source=site_inter&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box",
       "www.google.com?utm_source=site_foglio&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box")
output <- str_extract(x, "(?<=\\butm_source=)[^&]+")
output

[1] "site_corriere"        "site_rep"             "site_fattoquotidiano"
[4] "site_inter"           "site_foglio"

The logical change to your regex pattern is to express the query parameter value of utm_source as [^&]+, which will match the single following value only (and note that it also matches if utm_source were the last query parameter in the URL as well).

If by any chance your workflow already uses httr or httr2, you also have a URL parser:
urls <- 
  c("www.google.com?utm_source=site_corriere&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box",
    "www.google.com?utm_source=site_rep&utm_medium=display&utm_content=box",
    "www.google.com?utm_source=site_fattoquotidiano&utm_medium=social&utm_content=box",
    "www.google.com?utm_source=site_inter&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box",
    "www.google.com?utm_source=site_foglio&utm_medium=video&utm_content=box")

httr::parse_url(urls[1])$query$utm_source
#> [1] "site_corriere"
httr2::url_parse(urls[1])$query$utm_source
#> [1] "site_corriere"

sapply(urls, \(x) httr2::url_parse(x)$query$utm_source) |> unname()
#> [1] "site_corriere"        "site_rep"             "site_fattoquotidiano"
#> [4] "site_inter"           "site_foglio"


URL parsing is quite common task, so there are probably loads of other packages where it's (re)implemented with slightly different interfaces and return values, e.g. with urltools:
# param_get returns 1-column data.frame
urltools::param_get(urls, "utm_source")[,1]
#> [1] "site_corriere"        "site_rep"             "site_fattoquotidiano"
#> [4] "site_inter"           "site_foglio"

Created on 2024-11-10 with reprex v2.1.1
